# php+MySQL не хочет создавать поле в таблице

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени суток. Такая у меня проблема:
Запрос на создание таблицы(она не существует):

```
$query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS comments_". $comm." (title VARCHAR(50), commenter VARCHAR(30), message TEXT, `date` TIMESTAMP(0) NOT NULL default 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP') ENGINE=MYISAM ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC CHARACTER SET cp1251 COLLATE cp1251_general_ci";
mysql_query($query) or die ("Таблицы не существует и она не может быть созданна! ". mysql_error());
```

Заполнение полей таблицы:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO comments_". $comm." (title, message, commenter) VALUES ('$title', '$comment', '$user')";
    mysql_query($query) or die ("Ошибка при выполнении запроса.".$query. mysql_error());
```

Выдает ошибку: неизвестное поле commenter...
Проверил через MySQL Developer Studio - поле не создается. Скопировал запрос SQL на создание таблицы оттуда - тоже не помогает. Не могу понять что не так...

Comment: Если создать дополнительное поле в уже созданной таблице - оно активно и доступно для пхп. Но надо чтобы поле создавалось автоматически из кода пхп.

Comment: Интересный факт: в полном коде переменная $comm получает свое значение из $_REQUEST['comm'], но если задать переменной определенное значение вручную то запрос работает правильно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо - рылся-рылся и нашел... Извините - ошибка совсем в другом месте - перед переходом на страницу с созданием таблицы - происходит создание ее старого варианта(на другой странице) - без этого поля ... Вот и вся проблема. Еще раз спасибо :)

Comment: Ыыы .. 

Попробуйте также в бубен постучать и плюнуть через левое плечо! Поможет!!

Извините, не удержался. А по делу:

    $query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS comments_". $comm." (title VARCHAR(50), commenter VARCHAR(30), message TEXT, `date` TIMESTAMP(0) NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) ENGINE=MYISAM ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC CHARACTER SET cp1251 COLLATE cp1251_general_ci";
    echo $query;
    exit;

Что выведет ?

Comment: Как я уже писал - таблица создается, но без одного поля...

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS comments_5 (title VARCHAR(50), commenter VARCHAR(30), message TEXT, `date` TIMESTAMP(0) NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) ENGINE=MYISAM ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC CHARACTER SET cp1251 COLLATE cp1251_general_ci

Comment: Кстати - еще один факт: если страницу добавления коммента запустить, удалить созданную таблицу, и перезапустить страницу еще раз - то создается нормальная таблица...

Answer (score 2):

Простите за вмешательство, я конечно не знаю вашей задачи, но программно создавать таблицы не очень хорошо, если для примера, или теста, или обучения, да, но если у вас рабочий проект, то постарайтесь спроектировать БД таким образом чтобы она была финальной. Создавая программно таблицы можно нарваться на непредвиденные ошибки и чрезмерное разрастание БД.
Опытные программисты думаю меня поддержат.

Comment: Спасибо за совет - учту. Это мой первый проект для обучения. Делаю что-то вроде блога. А таблицы добавляются по одной для каждой записи в них хранятся комментарии... Не думал над тем, что их может стать слишком много :)

Comment: В учебном примере да, но в рабочем проекте это будет лишним. Создайте одну таблицу для записей в блоге, одну таблицу для коментов, ну и так далее.  
Таблицы умеют связываться один к одному, одна ко многим, многие ко многим, в общем данные задачи давно предусмотрены разработчиками БД.  
Даже если сейчас у вас для примера получится, советую сразу же переделать по правильному с фиксированной БД, лучше сразу в правильном направлении набивать руку.

Comment: Дело в том, что я знаю MySQL ну уровне - подключился, создал, заполнил, получил, отключился... Только позавчера взялся за него :) Вам виднее :)

Comment: Вот именно, делайте изначально все правильно. Вы уже 4 часа ищете решения этой проблемы, бросьте гиблое дело и начните делать все правильно. Создайте сразу БД и работайте с готовой, это в разы будет проще.

Answer (score 1):

Пишет ошибку при создании БД: `#1067 - Invalid default value for 'date'`
Раскавычьте `'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'`

Comment: Не помогло... Кстати - все остальные поля создаются и работают.
Только commenter не создается

Comment: помоему вы не знаете о чем говорите )

Comment: :) Это мой первый проект ... И тем не менее - таблица стоит на месте

Comment: А вы уверены, что таблицы не было ранее, без поля commenter? Попробуйте грохнуть ту, что сейчас есть и еще раз выполнить запрос. Просто поле само по себе не могло не создаться. Либо оно создастся, либо запрос не пройдет.

Comment: Таблицы не было...